# OleDb: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, mysql, oledb

Im trying to connect to a mysql databse stored on my laptop, im using oledb to connect to it but im getting the error (c#):

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll
```

From the line:

```
conn.Open();
```

Full code is:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=MySQLProv; Data Source=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\singe; User Id=******; Password=*************;";

            //error is here
            //-------------
            conn.Open();
            //-------------

            conn.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }

}
```

The full output i get is this:

```
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'D:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x2324 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x409c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'd:\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ConsoleApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll
```

-I have checked that i am using the correct connection string.

-I have checked the location of the database file.

-I am able to connect and make queries to the database using the workbench and popsql.

-I am using visual studio 2015 (2017 doesnt work on my laptop)

Comment: Does the code run with VS 2017 on another computer?  I suspect that the code is not backwards compatible with VS 2015, but not sure.  It appears the the code was compiled for Net 4.0  (v4.0.30319) which is a 32 bit Net Library for Windows XP.  Your laptop is probably Windows 7 or later which is 64 bit.  So I would make a copy of the project bin folder.  Then delete the bin folder and recompile which will force everything to be recompiled using 64 bit instead of 32 bit.  Then try again.  VS2015 is also 64 bit.

Comment: Yes it worked on 2017 on my friends computer, and it is windows 7,  could you please explain more about the solution, sorry I'm terrible with software and can't find any bin folder. Thanks for the quick reply btw

Comment: A Visual studio project main folder has a SLN file with a folder where source files are located.  The bin folder is with the source files.

Comment: i found the bin folder, made a copy, and deleted it, then ran the program and got the same error, however i couldnt find any sln file, all that was in the bin folder was a debug folder which contained .exe's, .xml's and .manifest's. is this the issue or am i looking in the wrong place?

Comment: i dont know if tis just appeared or i just didnt notice it, but i also get this:   Additional information: The 'MySQLProv' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: Check Control Panel : Admin Tools : ODBC data Source : Drivers.  The sln file is in the parent folder where source files are located.  It is not needed and contains similar info as the .proj file.

Comment: i have a32 bit and a 64 bit, im assuming i should use the 64 bit one

Comment: Before deleting the bin folder you were using 32 bit because the error was showing v4.0 30319.   I think that is why you didn't see the error 'MySQLProv' provider is not registered on the local machine.  Now that you deleted bin you are using 64 bit which is the default with VS 2015 and windows 7.  Windows 7 originally had a 32 bit option, so it depends if you have the Windows 7 32 bit or windows 7 64 bit version.

Comment: im so sorry, when i went to check weather it was 32 bit or 64 bit, i found out that im actually using windows 10, *facepalm*, but i am am using the 64 bit. (i can't find anywhere how to find out what version iam currently running, everything just tells me that the computer runs on x64, but im assuming that i downloaded x64. (tldr, windows 10 x64)

Comment: also i found the drivers but there was no sln file in them

Comment: Don't worry about the sln.  It should be in the root file of the project.